# install ubuntu14.04 lts with 64 bit

Tags: 14.04

I want to do a fresh install on my computer. I have an intel 64 bit CPU. I am wondering can I install this version: `ubuntu-14.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso`

I really want to install the 64 bit version. But the name contains amd, so I am not sure if it's compatible with my machine. Thank you!

Comment: You can read more about [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/53415/why-are-64-bit-distros-often-called-amd64) why does it call `amd64`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AMD64 is the same as x86-64, just another name for the same architecture - it doesn't have to do anything with actual cpu vendor.

Quoted from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64:

> x86-64 (also known as x64, x86_64 and AMD64) is the 64-bit version of
>   the x86 instruction set
>
> .... .....
>
> The original specification was
>   created by AMD, and has been implemented by AMD, Intel and VIA.
>   Various names are used for the instruction set; prior to the launch,
>   x86-64 and x86_64 were used, while upon the release AMD named it AMD64

Quoted from https://askubuntu.com/a/84775/150504

> It's merely a convention due to the fact that AMD created the 64-bit
>   extensions to the x86 (Intel 386/486/Pentium) instruction set. At that
>   time, Intel was pushing Itanium as the only 64-bit solution, and Intel
>   didn't copy AMD's extensions until it was clear that AMD had created
>   something that was being used widely. The #define AMD64 was used to
>   distingish this 64-bit instruction set from Intel's Itanium
>   instruction set.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can install it - amd64 (sometimes called x64) is the name of the architecture and it's not made specifically for AMD CPUs.